# How to plot the kmeans algorithm in pyspark?

Tags: python, plot, graph, pyspark, k-means

Is there any good way to plot the kmeans algorithm(plot the whole process of the algorithm, or part of it) in pyspark?

I have a fully trained model, but I want to plot the "before-proccess-after".

```
parsedData = rawData.map(lambda s: Vectors.dense([s['event_ref_index'],s['meter_id_index'],s['timestamp_index']]))

clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, maxIterations=300, initializationMode="random")
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What does "plot the algorithm" mean?

Comment: That I want to plot the whole process of the algorithm